# Selenium hangs in loops

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath

As I have n number of links on home page every link takes to different application. New tab/window will be opened after clicking on each link, in a new tab i need to check presence of the particular element(using xpath of the element which is passed from excel for all the applications). After checking the presence of the element I need to close child window and switch back to parent window and follow the same process to remaining links(1000+). My script works fine only when non of the application/window hangs, if any of the application not getting loaded or hangs then script unable to close child window and switch back to parent to continue testing with other links.

- How exactly page load works?
- I want to close child window after waiting for few seconds even if its loading the page and switch back to parent window

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a utility class once that handled windows and kept track of all the open window handles.  Using it, the project ran up to 4 open browser popup windows and then closes them down in that order.

See [the project here](https://raw.github.com/djangofan/selenium-gradle-example/master/commonlib/src/main/java/qa/webdriver/util/WebDriverUtils.java).

This could probably be improved a lot, but here is an example method from that class:

```
/**
 * Loops to determine if WebDriver.getWindowHandles() returns any
 *  additional windows that the allHandles cache does not currently
 *  contain. If new window is found that is not in the cache, switch 
 *  to that latest window and update allHandles cache.
 */
public static String handleNewWindow() {
    String newHandle = "";
    printHandles();
    Set<String> updatedHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    if ( updatedHandles.size() < handleCache.size() ) {
        mainHandle = "";
        LOGGER.info("Illegal state: actually, I saw a window close.");
        throw new IllegalStateException("This method handleNewWindow is not appropriate\n" +
                "in this case.  You are probably looking for the\n"+
                "use of the updateHandleCache method.");
    } else if ( updatedHandles.size() == handleCache.size() ) {
        LOGGER.info("handleNewWindow() will do nothing because there are no new window handles.");
    } else {
        if ( !updatedHandles.isEmpty() ) {
            for ( String windowId : updatedHandles ) {
                if ( !windowId.equals( mainHandle ) ) { // for all windows except main window
                    if ( !handleCache.contains( windowId) ) { // for child windows not in allHandles cache
                        newHandle = windowId; // set value of newly found window handle                     
                        LOGGER.info("-- Open window handle: " + newHandle + " (new window)" );
                    }
                }
            }
            if ( !newHandle.equals("") ) { // outside loop so it catches latest window handle if there are multiple
                LOGGER.info("Switch to new window.");
                driver.switchTo().window( newHandle ); // switch to new window handle
            }
        } else {
            mainHandle = "";
            throw new IllegalStateException("No browser window handles are open.");
        }
    }
    handleCache = updatedHandles; // updates remembered set of open windows
    return newHandle;
}
```

Comment: HI Djangofan... Here I don't have switching problem between windows.. If any child window hangs then selenium stop executing further links in the parent window.. Every thing works fine if non of the window hangs..This prob with FF, chrome and IE

Comment: It sounds to me like you just need to upgrade to a newer version of Selenium to catch-up with the behavior of the latest browsers.  Also, update your IE and Chrome binaries.

Comment: I am using selenium 2.39 and will check with updated binaries of the browsers